# KSH - Check return code on individual commands in find -maxdepth 0 $path -type f -mtime +$daysold -exec rm -fv {}\;

Tags: unix, find, return, ksh, rm

I am trying to figure out how to check the return codes on the `find` command and the `rm -fv` command in the following statement:

```
find -maxdepth 0 $path -type f -mtime +$daysold -exec rm -fv {}\;
```

Basically, if an error occurs, I want to know if it occurred in the `find` or the `rm` command and forward that information to our developers via e-mail. How would I go about this? I understand if I look at `$?`, it will just look at the statement as a whole.

Comment: Dump stderr output instead of return code. It contains error text in english.

Comment: or convert the `rm -fv` call to a script that manages reporting of errors from the `rm` command separately from `$?` status of find. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` uses the return code of the `-exec` command as a predicate: if the command was successful - the file matches.

Thus you can make the `find` to print all the files for which the `rm -fv` command has failed by negating the predicate with the `!`:

```
find -maxdepth 0 $path -type f -mtime +$daysold ! -exec rm -fv {} \; -print
```

(You have to add `-print` since the presence of `-exec` overrides the default implicit `-print`.)

You can redirect the output of the `find` into a file, and if the file is not empty, then you can e-mail it accordingly.

Comment: `find` predicates continue to amaze/baffle. Thanks for sharing.